# Pick a csv/xls file from SFTP Folder do some update and store again to SFTP folder

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I have a SFTP folder i want to pick latest file from there it should be csv/text/xls . then read file do some update with file and store again into SFTP folder with same name.

Comment: You can use a third-party library to communicate through SFTP.

Answer (score 0):

As per your requirement, you should use a Scheduler for your Java Program. Which can check and pick up the files from SFTP and do the processing and store there.

Java provides basic scheduling support, [Scheduling In Java](https://www.baeldung.com/scheduling-in-java-enterprise-edition). And you can also use 3rd party tools like, [Quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/)